# What is the best way to check IQueryable result set is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I just want to know what is the best way to check if an `IQueryable` result has no values.

eg. if we have a method like

```
public static IQueryable<Table> DisplayAll()
{
    var db = new DataContext();
    var list= from data in db.Table select data;
    return list;
}
```

and then we do something like this

```
var list = DisplayAll();
if(list != null)
{
     //do something --- in here even if the result set has no values it will
     // go to this line. It just say `enumeration yielded no results`
}
```

Any possible way to check the result set has content or not??

Thanks

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`list` will never be `null` with LINQ; it will simply represent an "empty collection" if need be. The way to test is with the `Any` extension method:

```
if (list.Any()) {
    // list has at least one item
}
```

Comment: But without a ToList() this could be very expensive.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Why? I 'd bet good money that in this particular example, `Any()` would result in a `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` and an integer comparison. Even if it goes the silly route of starting to enumerate a result set, how would `ToList` be faster?

Comment: @HenkHolterman hence the need to question whether you should be checking to see if the list contains anything or not, or simply trying to iterate over the results (bind) and not show anything if there are no results. The OP didn't specify why they wanted to check.

Comment: +1: How about if you want to get a `Count()`? Say if you want to ensure your query has only one result? I guess my concern is in the use of `Count()`, i.e., enumerating the query results.

Comment: @IAbstract: If you are expecting exactly (or at most) one result then you can use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`, which will throw as soon as it enumerates a second element.

Comment: @Jon: I don't want to throw - that is expensive. I'll post a question about it though.

Comment: This throws me an error when there is no data and I am not keen on using try catch, any other solution?

Answer (score 4):

An exception will be thrown if IQueryable yeilds no result. I use:

```
using System.Data.Entity; //for Async support in EF
var tQ = await _tableRepository.DisplayAll();
try { return await tQ.ToListAsync(); }
catch { return null; }
```

to trap the exception and return null; or an empty List if you prefer,

```
catch { return new List<Table>(); }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what works for me:

```
    public IQueryable SomeFunc()
    {
        IQueryable result = Repo.SomeLinqQuery();
        if (result.GetEnumerator().MoveNext() == false)
        {
            throw new Exception("Results empty");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: why you really need to do this?

Comment: This part is good though:  result.GetEnumerator().MoveNext() == false